# EFS sync task failing with Restart Call

Tags: amazon-web-services, efs

We have on-premise sync agent running. Every now and then sync task is failing with `Restart call` (Shows under activity under history tab).

What could be the issue ? I could not find any information about this in aws documentation or forum.

Comment: This [post](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2477) has a list of issues: swap file too small, too many logs files when syncing from the top level of the bucket, the AWS sync script itself (replaced). Are you transferring huge files?

Comment: Thank you will check it out. Usually total size is less than 500MB.

Answer (score 0):

Check the mounting types.
There are two types of mounting "Temporary Mount" and "Permanent Mount"
If you mount by using mount command then it is temporary mounting, when you restart your instances it will unmount.
After mounting open and edit fstab and insert your mounting path in that file then it won't unmount again.
Use this command "vi /etc/fstab" and edit the file.